# No detections using custom SSD Mobilenet model with OpenCV DNN module

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, machine-learning, neural-network

I have been using OpenCV's DNN module on a Raspberry Pi 4, which requires a frozen inference graph (.pb file) and corresponding text graph file (.pbtxt file).

With the pre-trained **ssd_mobilenet_v3_small_coco** from [TF1 model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf1_detection_zoo.md) and using the **tf_text_graph_ssd.py** script from [OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/dnn) to generate the pbtxt file, this runs successfully on the Raspberry at an average 5 FPS.

I then wanted to try and speed this up, by training this model for just one class.
After banging my head around of errors and dependency versions, I have gotten the training to work. I built a dataset, labelled the images, created all the necessary files. Used the **ssdlite_mobilenet_v3_small_320x320_coco.config** [from sample configs](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs), **set all the paths, pointed the fine-tune-checkpoint to the model folder, set number of classes to 1 and batch size to 16**.

The model_train.py runs and it appears to yield results although I'm not quite sure how to interpret them. I have trained it for 100K steps, then exported a frozen inference graph, and again used the **tf_text_graph_ssd.py** to generate a pbtxt file. **I run these on my raspberry pi app and it throws no errors, runs at 10FPS, but detects absolutely nothing.**

So either I'm doing something wrong in the training, or in the export or pbtxt generation. No idea where to go from here. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction. Below are some shots of the Tensorboard output.

Loss graphs:
[image: Loss graphs]

Precision Graphs:
[image: Precision Graphs]

Eval Images Tab:
[image: Eval Images Tab]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, as I did figure it out, and it may help others.

I was trying to use the frozen inference graph generated by [export_inference_graph.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) and trying to generate the text graph from that.)

In fact I should've been exporting the frozen inference graph using [export_tflite_ssd_graph.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection), and then using this frozen inference graph along with [tf_text_graph_ssd.py](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/dnn/) to generate the corresponding text graph.

Once I did this, I had the correct pb and pbtxt that ran perfectly with OpenCV's DNN module.